# Ember Model RESTAdapter nested endpoint

Tags: rest, ember.js, nested, endpoint, ember-model

I'm building a web app using Ember 1.5 and I use Ember Model 0.0.11 to link the app to an API.  I'm currently having trouble getting Ember Model to use nested API endpoints.

For instance, my app has a `User` model, which has a `hasMany` relationship with a `Post` model. Now, when I want to load the posts for a certain user, I'd like the `Post.findQuery('user_id', {user_id});` method to access the `GET /users/{user_id}/posts` endpoint. Instead, it seems that the Ember Model solution prefers to send the query as a parameter to the `GET /posts` endpoint.

Ember Model's `RESTAdapter` does allow for easy customization, but before I start coding a completely custom `RESTAdapter` I'd love to know if someone has already done this and how they solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for us to handle nested API routes was to have a links hash returned with the requested payload. If you can change the API output, this is the way to go for now. For example, when requesting a workspace, the returned JSON looks like this (excuse the escaped characters):

```
{
   "data":
      {
         "object":"workspace",
         "id":"wrk_krVZWGaJ",
         "organization_name":"Legros, Klein and Boehm",
         "workspace_name":"Legros, Klein and Boehm",
         "workspace_path":"legros, klein and boehm",
         "status":true,
         "credit_production":7,
         "credit_revision":16,
         "links":{
            "projects":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/projects",
            "productions":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/productions",
            "subscription":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/subscription",
            "assets":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/assets",
            "descriptions":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/descriptions",
            "roles":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/roles",
            "registrations":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/registrations",
            "users":"\/v1\/workspaces\/wrk_krVZWGaJ\/users"
         }
      }
}
```

The model defines the links as async hasMany relationships, i.e. `DS.attr('projects', {async: true})`. When the workspace is loaded from the store, the linked projects aren't included. When you use `{{#each workspace.projects}}` or `workspace.get('projects')` anywhere else, ember-data will make a GET request to `/v1/workspaces/wrk_krVZWGaJ/projects/`, rather than the default route of `/projects/`. Neato, eh?

More details on the [RESTAdapter findHasMany method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany).